# Angularjs Dropdown Multiselect: Toggle Check All and Uncheck All

Tags: angularjs, multi-select

The dropdown displays `Check All` and `Uncheck All` options. I wanted to have a toggle checkbox (e.g. Select All) instead of those options. How can we do that?

[image]

Comment: https://codepen.io/long2know/pen/PqLRyZ , you use this link

Comment: don't come here just for an answer. First attempt the problem and when you get stuck post your code along with what you are trying to do and then people will assist